# Why is "en" used in "j'en ai encore des frissons"?

Tags: grammaire, en

I encountered the sentence "j'en ai encore des frissons" in a Babbel lesson.

My understanding is that "en" is used to replace a partitive article and noun.

But "des frissons" has not been removed; what purpose does "en" serve here?

Comment: It would not replace frissons but something that has been mentioned before that. So you need to quote more of the text. I doubt it replaces here article + noun (As in *As-tu du pain ? Oui, j'en ai*.), it probably replaces part of a sentence. Does the answer [to this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/29078/358) help you ?

Comment: I'm the question it's marked a duplicate of, it's indicated that en isn't used to replace a partitive article and noun but rather to mean "this." Not a usage of en I've learned.

Comment: *en* is a word that can mean lots of things. https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-grammar/how-to-use-the-pronoun-en-in-french/ ; https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/en-adverbial-pronoun/